# Help with bones getting numbers in import from Mixamo

Tags: rigging, bones, import, mixamo

I've been exporting mixamo characters to fbx then import into Blender. Each time I do the bones names get appended with a number. But in the middle. So like mixamorig1:lefthand, instead of mixamorig:lefthand. It seems to be different numbers for different imports.

I honestly don't know where to start to troubleshoot. I'm only using blender as a go between to export to glb and import into Godot.

Any hints? If I even had a clue where to start I could research from there.

Comment: That's Mixamo's naming convention, nothing to do with Blender. You might be able to write a script to rename them in Blender but I don't know python so have no idea how easy it would be.

Comment: OK. Weird. The first time I downloaded a character it didn't have the numbers. I was hoping I was doing something wrong. I can build a custom BoneMap for Godot to solve this on that side. Just annoying to need multiple bonemaps. Thank you.